# How to copy a .txt file in data folder into the Download folder in Android using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to copy a .txt file that's in my app's package folder to the Download folder when a button is pressed. This is the code for the button:

```
binding_second.btnDone.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                var this_dir = getExternalFilesDir(this_filename)
                var target_dir = File("sdcard/Download/"+ this_filename)
                this_dir?.copyTo(target_dir)
                println("Copy succeeded")
            }
        })
```

When this code is run, instead of copying the .txt file and its content from the source location and making a copy in the Download folder, it creates a folder with the name of the .txt file within the Download folder. I would appreciate any help at all!

Answer (score 1):

You're confused about how getExternalFilesDir works.  The parameter to it is NOT a filename within the directory.  It's the type of external file directory, such as Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES for pictures.  Since you passed an invalid value, you're getting the default directory.  Then you're copying that directory.

What you want instead is `var this_dir = File(getExternalFilesDir(null), this_filename);`  That will get a file with the given name relative to the getExternalFilesDir directory.

Comment: Thank you, I made the necessary correction but now it is throwing an error "The source file doesn't exist"

Comment: @stressedkid Probably you're using the wrong base directory.  How are you generating this text file, are you sure you're looking in the right place for it?